# How to set connection manager offline property set False in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

The connection manager shows an error :The connection manager will not accuire a connection because the connection manager offline mode property is true.I can not find this property!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-clicking  in the Connection Managers area of SSIS Designer and then clicking.

[image: Work Offline].

or 
[image]